# Why do I need $parent to enable the function in ng-click when using ion-scroll?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using the following versions:

1. Ionic, v1.0.0-beta.14
2. AngularJS v1.3.6

**Route configuration:**

```
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('manager_add', {
            url: '/managers/add',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/mdl.role_members/views/add.html',
            controller: 'ManagerAddController'
        });
});
```

**Controller configuration:**

```
myApp.controller('ManagerAddController', function ($scope, $state, $ionicLoading, $filter, ContactService, ManagersService, RoleRequest, RoleRequestsSentService, ToastrService) {

    $scope.role_request = RoleRequest.new();
    $scope.showContactSearch = false;

    $scope.managers = ManagersService.collection();
    $scope.$watchCollection("managers", function( newManagers, oldManagers ) {
        if(newManagers === oldManagers){ return; }
        $scope.managers = newManagers;
        $scope.contactsToBeInvited = getNotInvitedContacts();
    });

    $scope.contacts = ContactService.collection();
    $scope.$watchCollection("contacts", function( newContacts, oldContacts ) {
        if(newContacts === oldContacts){ return; }
        $scope.contacts = newContacts;
        $scope.contactsToBeInvited = getNotInvitedContacts();
    });

    $scope.contactsToBeInvited = getNotInvitedContacts();
    function getNotInvitedContacts() {
        var notinvited = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.contacts, function(contact) {
            if(angular.isObject($scope.managers)) {
                var results = $filter('filter')($scope.managers, {member_id: Number(contact.contact_id)}, true);
                if (results.length == 0) {
                    this.push(contact);
                }
            } else {
                this.push(contact);
            }
        }, notinvited);

        return notinvited;
    }

    $scope.search_contact = "";
    $scope.search = function(contact) {
        if($scope.search_contact === "" || $scope.search_contact.length === 0) {
            return true;
        }

        $scope.showContactSearch = true;
        var found = false;
        if(contact.display_name) {
            found = (contact.display_name.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.search_contact.toLowerCase()) > -1);
            if(found) { return found; }
        }
        if(contact.contact.getFullName()) {
            found = (contact.contact.getFullName().toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.search_contact.toLowerCase()) > -1);
            if(found) { return found; }
        }
        if(contact.contact.email) {
            found = (contact.contact.email.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.search_contact.toLowerCase()) > -1);
            if(found) { return found; }
        }

        return found;
    }

    $scope.selectContact = function(contact) {
        $scope.search_contact = contact.contact.getFullName();

        // TODO: Make dynamic role
        $scope.role_request.role_id = 4;
        $scope.role_request.email = contact.contact.email;
    };

    $scope.addRoleMember = function(valid) {
        if($scope.role_request.email === "") { return; }
        if(!valid) { return; }

        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: 'Please wait...'
        });

        RoleRequestsSentService.add($scope.role_request).then(function(roleJsonResponse){
            ToastrService.toastrSuccess('Request send', 'We have send an invite to '+ $scope.search_contact +'.');
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            $state.go('managers');
        });
    }
});
```

**View configuration:**

```
<ion-view view-title="ManagerAdd" >

    <ion-content class="has-header scroll="true">
        <div class="content">

            <div class="list">
                <div class="item item-border">
                    <p>Some text</p>
                </div>
            </div>


            <form name="managerForm">
                <div class="list">

                    <div class="item item-divider">
                        Some text
                    </div>

                    <div class="item item-border">
                        <form name="fillForm">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label item-textarea">
                                    <span class="input-label border-none">Personal message: <span class="text-red required">*</span></span>
                                    <textarea name="message" ng-model="role_member.message" required></textarea>
                                </label>
                                <p ng-show="managerForm.message.$dirty && managerForm.message.$error.required"
                                   class="error-message">Message required!</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="item item-input">
                                    <span class="input-label">Search on name <span class="text-red required">*</span></span>
                                    <input type="text" name="search_contact" ng-model="$parent.search_contact">
                                </label>

                                <div class="searchResultBox" ng-show="showContactSearch">
                                    <ion-scroll direction="y" class="scrollArea">
                                        <div class="list">

                                            <a class="item item-border item-avatar pointer" ng-repeat="contact in $parent.filteredContacts = (contactsToBeInvited | filter:search:false)" ng-click="$parent.selectContact(contact)">
                                                <img src="{{ contact.getImage('thumbnail') }}">
                                                <h2>{{contact.getIconName()}}</h2>
                                                <p>City: {{contact.contact.city}}</p>
                                            </a>

                                        </div>
                                    </ion-scroll>

                                    <div class="notFound pointer" ng-hide="filteredContacts.length">
                                        <h3>Nobody found</h3>
                                        <p>You can only search through existing contacts</p>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-actions">
                    <button type="submit" class="button button-block regie-button" ng-click="addRoleMember(registerForm.$valid)">
                        Sent request
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>

            <p class="text-red" style="text-align:center; font-size:14px; font-weight: 400;">* required</p>

        </div>
    </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

As you can see in the view I need to use `$parent` to the following fields to get it to work:

- `ng-model="$parent.search_contact"`
- `ng-repeat="contact in $parent.filteredContacts = (contactsToBeInvited | filter:search:false)"`
- `ng-click="$parent.selectContact(contact)"`

I really don't understand why this is necessary because the complete view is using the same controller. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the inheritance. Between your controller's scope and those fields, there are several new scopes (ion-content, ion-scroll and probably others).

So for example the `ng-model="search_content"`. When you write in there, it is going to create a `search_content` variable inside the `ion-content` scope (or an intermediary scope if there is any that I didn't see). Since `search_content` is being created inside `ion-content`, your controller won't see it.

If you do `$parent.search_content` it will create it in the parent content (AKA the controller's scope).

You shouldn't do that, what `$parent` is for you today, tomorrow it can point to anything else (because you could add a new scope in between without knowing it so $parent will then point to the `ion-content`.

So instead of doing that, you need to use objects and no primitives, for example:

```
ng-model="form.search_contact"
```

Thank to that, it will look for the `form` object through the prototype chain until it finds it on the controller's scope and use it (just what you need).

Read [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) which is hundred times better than my explanation.

Comment: Thank you this solved my issue on this page. I thought I could solve another issue on a different view and controller with the same solution. Because there the child scope also was different from the parent. But I can't get it to work, see next: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190624/ng-click-not-working-in-ion-scroll-even-when-all-scope-variables-are-in-an-obje

Answer (score 3):

This is a very typical angular scoping issue.  Ion-view creates a new child scope and uses prototypical inheritance: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Three are several ways to solve:

- always use a dot: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot
- use the 'controller as' syntax: http://www.johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/