# What is the best way to debug angular code?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm a newbie in the Angular space. I've been having trouble debugging my code. Any methods proven more effective in debugging Angular?

Comment: I usually use FireFox (FIreBug) because I can inspect the Angular scope. For all other js testing, I use Chrome DevTools

Comment: having what trouble? Question is pretty vague

Comment: Write unit and integration tests

Answer (score 7, accepted):

open the developer console in the chrome browser, this allows you to:

- set breakpoints and see whats going on in your code
- use the console in the developer tools while you are waiting in breakpoints to execute some code or check the contents of variables
- use the "select element" tool to select any HTML element, then in the console type "$scope" to see what's on the $scope of this element.

general tipps:

- use some console.log statment like "running ControllerXYZ now" so you see, when your controllers are executed or when you are transitioning between states.
- When using ui-router I find it extremly important to add a console.log statement into $stateChangeStart,  $stateChangeSuccess and $stateChangeError event handlers, that shows you when you transition between states or when errors happen on state transitions, without that I am blind...
- adding some `{{anImportantVariable | json}}` into html often is enough to debug stuff.

and the most important: if everything looks ok, and it still does not work, the problem is in 99%:

- either a scoping issue (see here: [Why do I need $parent to enable the function in ng-click when using ion-scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187902/why-do-i-need-parent-to-enable-the-function-in-ng-click-when-using-ion-scroll/30188744#30188744))
- or a spelling mistake and a directive is not found (often because of the CamelCase in  JS to dash-case in HTML: e.g. `ngShow` directive in JS is `ng-show` in HTML, and `isOpen`attribute in JS is `is-open` in HTML)

Comment: These tips are really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

When it comes to inspecting the state: even though I always (irony) write unit tests for each and every conditional in my code (so I normally don't need to debug stuff) this is so far my favourite technique:

```
<pre ng-show='mymodel.debugPlz'>{{ mymodel.something | json }}</pre>
```

Simple example : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bp9y5ojs/)

Answer (score 3):

`Chrome DevTools` usually get the job done pretty well. You can insert a `debugger;` statement anywhere in the code and if `Chrome DevTools` are open, the code will stop there and you can further add breakpoint and traverse lines one by one. Other than that, there are a few extensions you can use by just searching for `Angular` in the Chrome Webstore. These usually help with inspecting `$scope`

Comment: Specifically I'd recommend checking out Batarang because its supported by Angular.js core https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-7mhcHXSfM

Comment: Batarng was great for a while, then they updated it and many features were broken.  Also, it is all but useless for debugging any jsFiddle or Plunker code.

Answer (score 0):

what about using [AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk) chrome extention

it gives you a nice overview of the current scope within the selected element

as you see in the screenshot there is a new scope tab

[image]