# Angular Material: $scope can't get ng-model in md-tab

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" class="sample tabsdemoDynamicTabs" layout="column" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content class="md-padding">
    <md-tabs md-selected="selectedIndex">
      <md-tab label="Login">

        <form name="loginForm">
          <md-input-container>
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="login_username" ng-model="login_username" required>
          </md-input-container>
          <md-input-container>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="login_passwd" ng-model="login_passwd" required>
          </md-input-container>

          <md-button class="md-button md-raised" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" ng-click="login()">Login</md-button>
        </form>
      </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
  </md-content>

</div>
```

JS:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
      .module('MyApp')
      .controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);

  function AppCtrl ($scope) {
    $scope.login = function(){
      alert($scope.login_username);
      alert(this.login_username);
    }
  }
})();
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGdqwa

If I move the form outside `md-tabs`, everything works well.

Why `$scope` can't get `ng-model` in `md-tabs`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things:

1. you are not adding `ngMaterial` as dependency in your module
   like this
2. create an object in you controller

---

```
   (function () {
      'use strict';
      angular
          .module('MyApp',['ngMaterial'])
          .controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);

      function AppCtrl ($scope) {

          $scope.login = {
              username: 'email@example.com', 
              passwd: ''
          };

        $scope.dologin = function(){
          alert($scope.login.username);
          alert(this.login.username);
        }
      }
    })();
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <form name="loginForm" >
            <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
              <md-tab label="login">
          <md-input-container>
            <label>Username</label>
              <input type="text" name="login_username" ng-model="login.username" required />
          </md-input-container>
          <md-input-container>
            <label>Password</label>
              <input type="password" name="login_passwd" ng-model="login.passwd" required />
          </md-input-container>

          <md-button class="md-button md-raised" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" ng-click="dologin()">Login</md-button>

              </md-tab>
              <md-tab label="other tabs"></md-tab>
              <md-tab label="other tabs"></md-tab>
              <md-tab label="other tabs"></md-tab>
              <md-tab label="other tabs"></md-tab>
            </md-tabs>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**fiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/salalaslam/m1u8hzxk/1/)

**EXPLANATION**: custom directives come with their own scope, when you use `ng-model` the variable falls in to the default scope, in your case `md-tabs`, to work-around this you can initialize the `ng-model` in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the dot.

You are losing scope of your model by not attaching it to an object.

Instead of

ng-model="login_username"

Try using

ng-model="login.username"

Answer (score 0):

That should show a error, if any, change:`.module('MyApp')` to `.module('MyApp', [])`

Answer (score 0):

This is a angular scope inheritance Problem, md-tabs is using a child scope. See this question, the same solutions will work for you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30188744/2766511